# How to use javascript object in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, npapi

Thanks in advance .

I am creating one function as follows .
//requestFile is implemented in NPAPI Plugin , Getting initFS as an NPObject when task is complete i am calling NPN_InvokeDefault on this object.

```
window.requestFile("test",true,initFS);
//After this function initFS is getting called.
function initFS(fs) {
 alert('Inside initFS'); //alert is coming.
 //testFunc is implemented in NPAPI Plugin, it will return true if it is get called
 alert(fs.testFunc());   // It is not getting called.
 alert(fs.testCall());   //It is not getting called.
 }
function testCall() {
alert('Inside testCall function');
}
```

I  am not getting it which kind of object is returned from Plugin after calling NPN_InvokeDefault. and how to use it in javascript . Specifically i want to return NPObject specially for my plugin , and want to call Plugin methods from javascript.

How to use Asynchronous Javascipt functions with NPAPI Plugins ? any  sample will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJHyN/1/)) as a starting point:

```
    var testcall=function() {
    alert('Inside testCall function');
    }

    var fs={
        testFunc: function(){console.log("succes")},
        testCall:testcall
    }


    //After this function initFS is getting called. 

    initFS(fs) //<--PASS in fs also

function initFS(fs) {
     alert('Inside initFS');
     //testFunc is implemented in NPAPI Plugin, it will return true if it is get called
     fs.testFunc();   // It is not getting called.
     fs.testCall();   //It is not getting called.
     }
```

You need to pass in the `fs` object into `initFS`